# I want to make a dynamic 2 columned table in html based on the record and its content

Tags: html, css, dompdf, column-count

I have an array of content. I want to make a dynamic table. Can be using DIVs as well. I want to loop my array and I want the data to be displayed like this.

[image]

It should adjust the count and height of table automatically because I have to use it in DOMPDF.

**The property of CSS column-count is not working so i want a work around and I will reward 50 bounty for whoever helps me solve this issue.**

Comment: I think you can use Flexbox or gridview to create a layout like this (for css part). But i don't know if this solution can work for dompdf

Comment: can you help me with the flexbox / gridview part?

Comment: [test](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvoPZR)  try this, its a base solution with simple css (but i don't know if it can help you)

Comment: Thankyou so much. There are a few things. The data will be dynamic. So we can't give fixed height. The heights have to be adjusted automatically. Does this makes sense? :(

Comment: Yeah you must give height:auto; or min-height: somepx; I'll write an answer

Comment: Also the loop will be single. We can not use 2 individual divs. It will be one div but the content will automatically move to right.

Comment: If you want to post a bounty, just post a bounty; don't tell people you are willing to post a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic solution:
HTML

```
<div class='wrapper cf'>

  <div class='col-left'>
    <div class='one'></div>
    <div class='two'></div>
    <div class='foo'></div>
    <div class='type'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-right'>
    <div class='oneone'></div>
    <div class='twotwo'></div>
    <div class='foofoo'></div>
    <div class='typetype'></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
.wrapper{
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
  min-height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col-left,.col-right{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  min-height:100px;
}
.col-right{float:right;}
.one{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:20px;}
.two{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:25px;}
.foo{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:120px;}
.type{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:80px;}

.oneone{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:40px;}
.twotwo{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:35px;}
.foofoo{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:120px;}
.typetype{border:1px solid #000;width:100%;height:110px;}

.col-left div:last-child,.col-right div:last-child{border-bottom:none;}
```

I give fixed height only for example .

The cf class is taken by gallagher [site](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

To achieve this result dinamically you can use for example a foreach function to loop an array.